# Extract youtube stats for nerds through an API

Tags: javascript, python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any available youtube API to get stats for nerds?

[image: stats for nerds data]

I have looked around for statistics but they point out to viewCount, likeCount etc. I am particularly looking for stats for nerds data available on right click of a video.

```
   URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=YOUR_API_KEY
     &part=snippet,statistics&fields=items(id,snippet,statistics)

Description: This example adds the fields parameter to remove all
             kind and etag properties from the API response.

API response:

{
 "videos": [
  {
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-06-20T22:45:24.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "description": "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "categoryId": "28"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3057",
    "likeCount": "25",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "17",
    "commentCount": "12"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the [Resource representation of Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), if you're looking for stats for nerds. You can get the following data:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  ...
  "fileDetails": {
    "fileName": string,
    "fileSize": unsigned long,
    "fileType": string,
    "container": string,
    "videoStreams": [
      {
        "widthPixels": unsigned integer,
        "heightPixels": unsigned integer,
        "frameRateFps": double,
        "aspectRatio": double,
        "codec": string,
        "bitrateBps": unsigned long,
        "rotation": string,
        "vendor": string
      }
    ],
    "audioStreams": [
      {
        "channelCount": unsigned integer,
        "codec": string,
        "bitrateBps": unsigned long,
        "vendor": string
      }
    ],
    "durationMs": unsigned long,
    "bitrateBps": unsigned long,
    "creationTime": string
  },
  "processingDetails": {
    "processingStatus": string,
    "processingProgress": {
      "partsTotal": unsigned long,
      "partsProcessed": unsigned long,
      "timeLeftMs": unsigned long
    },
    "processingFailureReason": string,
    "fileDetailsAvailability": string,
    "processingIssuesAvailability": string,
    "tagSuggestionsAvailability": string,
    "editorSuggestionsAvailability": string,
    "thumbnailsAvailability": string
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stats For Nerds are retrieved by the player via an internal Youtube API (InnerTube).

URL: [https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player?key=[DERIVATED_API_KEY]](https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player?key=%5BDERIVATED_API_KEY%5D)

Play with web developper to get the derivated API key and disable CORS via "--web-security" to allow cross domain ajax calls.

for Loudness info :

```
      function getLoudness(videoId) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player?key="+ytApiKeyV1,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          data: JSON.stringify({
            "videoId": videoId,
            "context": {
              "client": {
                "clientName": "WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER",
                "clientVersion": "1.20211110.01.01"
              },
              "thirdParty": {
                "embedUrl": "https://xxx.xxxxx.tld/"
              }
            }
          }),
          success: function(response) {
            if(response.playerConfig.audioConfig) {
              setLoudness(response.playerConfig.audioConfig);
            }
          }
        })
      }
```